# nginx memory pool corrupted?

Tags: c, nginx

I have a library that expects a `const char *src` in the constructor. As below:

`MYCLASS::MYCLASS(const char *src)`

I'm trying to use it from a nginx module to pass the value of a cookie to this library and I'm getting some memory corruption.

I couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong at this point. The cookie value reported on the debug of 'cookie' is always correct, but the one reported on u_cookie is only correct on the first request, after nginx serves other request and the pool is somehow used by others, the value returned always contains an additional character.

```
ngx_str_t cookie = (ngx_str_t)ngx_string("THECOOKIE");
ngx_int_t location;
ngx_str_t cookie_value;
location = ngx_http_parse_multi_header_lines(&r->headers_in.cookies, &cookie, &cookie_value);

ngx_log_debug1(NGX_LOG_DEBUG_HTTP, r->connection->log, 0,"cookie: \"%V\"", &cookie_value);

u_char *u_cookie = (u_char *)ngx_pcalloc(r->pool, cookie_value.len);
ngx_copy(u_cookie, cookie_value.data, cookie_value.len);
ngx_log_debug1(NGX_LOG_DEBUG_HTTP, r->connection->log, 0,"u_cookie: \"%s\"", u_cookie);

MYCLASS myclass( (const char*)u_cookie );
```

output in the log looks like this ..

> 2015/09/30 04:49:32 [debug] cookie:   "405JanIN9ztP/snEzyucny8KdgN"
>
> 2015/09/30 04:49:32 [debug] u_cookie: "405JanIN9ztP/snEzyucny8KdgNo"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `ngx_copy` would only copy N chars (where N - is the length of your cookie). But you need to set the null string terminator as well! Like this:

```
u_char *u_cookie = (u_char *)ngx_pcalloc(r->pool, cookie_value.len + 1); // +1 for null char
ngx_copy(u_cookie, cookie_value.data, cookie_value.len);
u_cookie[cookie_value.len] = 0
```

Comment: I ended up finding the same answer from a friend, but got the email notification of this slightly later. The only difference is that his solution uses: u_cookie[cookie_value.len] = '\0' which turns out to be the same.